# Summarizing MulitLineStrings to one line

Tags: qgis

I want to show my multilinestring as one line, like one the picture below.

The left line is correct.

[image: left: correct, right: wrong]

What I've got now is:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your data for testing purposes ?

Answer (score 0):

Use network tools like [Shortest path (point to layer)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisshortestpathpointtolayer) to connect one of the end-points (like e.g. no. 11 in your 2nd screenshot) to all other ends (like no 15,17,19, 10,12,14,16,18 etc.). Like this, just the shortest connection will be retained.

Explode the resulting lines and delete duplicate geometries. Befor using the network tool, make sure all lines are properly connect to a network.